# Probability mass function $p_X (v_{k+1}) = \overline F (v_k) - \overline F (v_{k+1})$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X$ be a positive random discrete variable with support $V=\{v_1,v_2,v_3,...\}$ (we assume $0 \leq v_1< v_2<v_3<...$). We also assume $\lim_{x \to \infty} x \overline F(x) = 0$.

We also know that for $k \in N$, $x \in [v_k, v_{k+1})$, $ \overline F (x) = \overline F(v_k),$
            and that for $x \in [0, v_1)$, $\overline F(x) = 1$.

> My question is: If $p_X (x)$ is the probability mass function of $X$, how do I prove that 
>   $$p_X (v_{k+1}) = \overline F (v_k) - \overline F (v_{k+1})$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that by definition,

$$F(x) = P(X \leq x)$$

and so you have

$$F(x) = \sum_{v\in V, v\leq x}p_X(v)$$

such that

$$F(v_k) = \sum_{i=1}^k p_X(v_i)$$

and

$$F\left(v_{k+1}\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}p_{X}\left(v_{i}\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{k}p_{X}\left(v_{i}\right)+p_{X}\left(v_{k+1}\right).$$

If you subtract one from the other, you get

$$F\left(v_{k+1}\right)-F\left(v_{k}\right)=p_{X}\left(v_{k+1}\right)$$

and knowing that $F\left(x\right)=1-\bar{F}\left(x\right)$, you simply get the answer you were looking for

$$p_{X}\left(v_{k+1}\right)=\bar{F}\left(v_{k}\right)-\bar{F}\left(v_{k+1}\right).$$

It's funny because I have the exact same question in my final project from my probability class. Hope this helped!

Comment: Yes this did help, thank you!